# Is there a WordPress theme or plugin with built-in user management

Tags: theme-development

For building a cashback site, is there a WordPress theme or plugin that offers custom user registration + 'My account' panel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just echoing what Chip already said: **Themes** are for *presentation*, **plugins** are for functionality.  Custom user registration and a 'My Account' panel would be in the realm of custom functionality.

To quote another WordPress developer:

> If you're building a bathroom and you change the wallpaper, the toilet shouldn't disappear, too.

Themes are the look and feel of your site and should be capable of being interchanged and swapped out easily.  Changing the theme, though, shouldn't remove your custom features (i.e. user management tools).  This is why they should be housed in a plugin rather than the theme.

That said, Chip also recommended an outstanding system: [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/).

If that's not quite what you're looking for, check out these as well:

- [Custom User Registration Lite](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/custom-user-registration-lite/)
- [WP User Registration](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-user-registration/)
- [Simplr User Registration Form](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/simplr-registration-form/)

Finally, since the custom work you need done might fall outside the realm of *any* existing plugin, you might consider listing the project on [jobs.wordpress.net](http://jobs.wordpress.net) and hiring a developer to build the system for you.

Answer (score 0):

Themes shouldn't be incorporating user management. Themes are for *presentation* of content.

Try the [Members Plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/members/) instead.